# Creality CP-01 3-in-1 printer firmware reset

Tags: firmware

I bought a Creality CP-01 3-in-1 printer, all working well, until I had an email saying there's an update for your 3D printer.

I downloaded and installed the firmware... and that's when things went bad, the printer head thinks that the front left of the plate is the center so it can't print anything.

I've tried Creality and they say that the update was not for my printer (why then did I get the email ?) only the original firmware is for my printer and you can get it from their website.

I must admit that I'm a bit stupid (no sorry a lot stupid) when it comes to 3D printers, and that is the problem, the firmware update was a file you installed on the printer and job done even though it's wrong.

I've downloaded the files needed but they are not in the right format and everything I try doesn't work.